# How Can I Create a New Column 'Month' From a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS Format Using Lubridate?

Tags: r, date, lubridate, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column of just the month from the following format using lubridate:

2020-01-01 00:00:00
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Thank you in advance.

My table is titled 'weather4' and thus far I have the following:

```
> weather4 %>% 
+     mutate(Year = year(weather4$valid),
+            Month = month(weather4$valid),
+            Day = day(weather4$valid))
```

image of output generated

[image]

Original Data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`weather4$valid` is full of NAs in your sample. Does it have any valid data?

I doubt you need year(weather4$valid) you are piping weather4 to it so just year(valid) is all you usually need...

Assuming valid has a date in it?

Now if it does... It also thinks it is a character judging by the table so you need to change it to a  "date" or date-time.

So I would suggest:

```
year(as.Posixtct(valid, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

You might want to do that once and pipe the result...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I added a new screenshot of the tibble with the data. You'll see the date & time formatting there. The 'image of output generated' was just what came up in my console after I ran the code I posted.

Comment: So what does: weather4 %>% year(as.Posixtct(valid, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) produce?

Comment: And what is the  class of valid i.e. tell us the output of class(weather4$valid)